# Eclipse Indigo: C/C++ Breakpoints don't work after installing PTP

Tags: eclipse, breakpoints, eclipse-indigo

After I installed Parallel Tools Platform (PTP) on my Eclipse classic, all my breakpoints for C/C++ applications stopped working. When creating a breakpoint, instead of making a tiny blue dot, Eclipse puts in a large green dot (indicating a breakpoint used in MPI applications). Since my project is a C/C++ project, these 'parallel' breakpoints are completely ignored during debug mode.

Anyone know how to reset the debug settings to C/C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check Run->Breakpoint Types->C/C++ Breakpoints. Mine was set to Parallel Breakpoints.